# I'm looking to know if I am implementing the Proxy Pattern correctly

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, interface

I am currently working hard to improve my code quality & apply design patterns. Today was dedicated to the Proxy Pattern.

My goal was to let a AuthService class act as a manager for any authentification service I may use in the future.

The user should be able to instantiate any service's class as a parameter to AuthService, so that there'd be no hassle when the need to change the service arises: all you'd need is to update the parameter.

For that purpose, I created an AuthInterface interface in Typescript which would be implemented by the AuthService manager componement & the actual services modules. I tried very hard to respect the SOLID principles by using dependency injection instead of using external code.

This being said, I am unsure if this design is an actual implementation of the Proxy pattern, or if  I turned it into an anti-pattern by adding too much complexity.

Please find the code below:

```
// The interface for AuthService & any auth module

interface AuthInterface<ServiceType, UserType> {
  init(initCallback?: () => ServiceType): ServiceType;
  signIn(
    authProvider?: ServiceType,
    signIncallback?: (authProvider?: ServiceType) => boolean | never | object
  ): boolean;
  getID(
    authProvider?: ServiceType,
    getIDCallback?: (authProvider?: ServiceType) => UserType
  ): UserType;
}

// The AuthService component which takes any authentification module. Is this the Proxy pattern?

class AuthService<ServiceType, UserType>
  implements AuthInterface<ServiceType, UserType>
{
  SomeService;
  constructor(SomeService: AuthInterface<ServiceType, UserType>) {
    this.SomeService = SomeService;
  }

  init(initCallback: () => ServiceType) {
    return this.SomeService.init(initCallback);
  }

  signIn(
    authProvider: ServiceType,
    signIncallback: (authProvider?: ServiceType) => boolean | never
  ) {
    return this.SomeService.signIn(authProvider, signIncallback);
  }

  getID(
    authProvider: ServiceType,
    getIDCallback: (authProvider?: ServiceType) => UserType
  ) {
    return this.SomeService.getID(authProvider, getIDCallback);
  }
}

// An authentification module, here Firebase, to add as a parameter to AuthService

class FirebaseAuth<ServiceType, UserType>
  implements AuthInterface<ServiceType, UserType>
{
  init(initCallback: () => ServiceType) {
    return initCallback();
  }

  signIn(
    authProvider: ServiceType,
    signIncallback: (authProvider?: ServiceType) => boolean | never
  ) {
    return signIncallback(authProvider);
  }

  getID(
    authProvider: ServiceType,
    getIDCallback: (authProvider?: ServiceType) => UserType
  ) {
    return getIDCallback(authProvider);
  }
}
```

I am new to Typescript, so please do not hesitate to tell me where the code can be improved.

I would be very grateful for any clarification. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am currently working hard to improve my code quality & apply design patterns

That's not the same thing. Design Patterns are standard solutions to standard design problems - but solving problems you don't have is a waste of effort.

> The user should be able to instantiate any service's class as a parameter to AuthService, so that there'd be no hassle when the need to change the service arises: all you'd need is to update the parameter.

That doesn't require the Proxy Pattern, plain old polymorphism can do this just fine:

```
const ActiveAuthService: AuthInterface = new FirebaseAuth();
```

That makes the users of `ActiveAuthService` unaware of which authentication method is in use, and changing the active authentication method involves changing that single line of code. There is no reason to delegate every single method, let alone manually.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I can now pinpoint exactly why I felt I was writing a big bloated anti pattern. Thank you!